# Uneven chunking in python

Tags: python, iterable, chunking

Given a list of chunk sizes, how would you partition an iterable into variable-length chunks? I'm trying to coax `itertools.islice` without success yet.

```
for chunk_size in chunk_list: 
   foo(iter, chunk_size)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an `iter` object of your iterable so you can call `islice` on it with a particular size, and pick up where you left off on the next iteration. This is a perfect use for a generator function:

```
def uneven_chunker(iterable, chunk_list):
    group_maker = iter(iterable)
    for chunk_size in chunk_list:
        yield itertools.islice(group_maker, chunk_size)
```

Example:

```
>>> iterable = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> chunk_size = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for item in uneven_chunker(iterable, chunk_size):
...     print ''.join(item)
...
t
he
 qu
ick
brown
 fox j
```